# cannot import name 'animation' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Code:

`from matplotlib import animation`

Output:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'animation' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import)`

The motplotlib version is 3.3.4

Comment: try this:`from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation`

Comment: ... or `import matplotlib.animation as animation`

Answer (score 2):

simply update matplotlib using `pip install --upgrade matplotlib` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem after tracking down the file path, I've always been using spyder of Anaconda, so i uninstalled and installed matplotlib using anaconda prompt over and over again, however, the problem is not error in anaconda, but python37 idle, it seems that if a packege is installed in idle, the spyder will run that one first(which is a bad one in my case), just by deleting matplotlib in python37 idle, the problem is solved at last

Answer (score 0):

Do a fresh installation:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib 
pip install matplotlib --force-reinstall --user
```